# How can i implement iAd using singleton class

Tags: objective-c, ios5, singleton, iad, xcode4.3

I want to implement iAd in my viewController so that i created the singleton class for iAd here the code that i used but it doesnt display iAd in my viewController.

> adWhirlSingleton.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "iAd/ADBannerView.h"
@interface adWhirlSingleton : NSObject <ADBannerViewDelegate> {
    ADBannerView *adView;
    UIViewController *displayVC;
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) ADBannerView *adView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIViewController *displayVC;
+(id)sharedAdSingleton;
-(void)adjustAdSize:(CGFloat)x:(CGFloat)y;
@end
```

---

> adWhirlSingleton.m

```
#import "adWhirlSingleton.h"
@implementation adWhirlSingleton

static adWhirlSingleton* _sharedAdSingleton = nil;
@synthesize adView, displayVC;

+(id)sharedAdSingleton
{
@synchronized(self)
{
    if(!_sharedAdSingleton)
         _sharedAdSingleton = [[self alloc] init];
    return _sharedAdSingleton;
}
return nil;
}

+(id)alloc
{
@synchronized([adWhirlSingleton class])
{
    NSAssert(_sharedAdSingleton == nil, @"Attempted to allocate a second instance of a   singleton.");
    _sharedAdSingleton = [super alloc];
    return _sharedAdSingleton;
}

return nil;
}

-(id)init
{
self = [super init];
if (self != nil) {
    // initialize stuff here
    self.adView.delegate=self;
}
return self;
}

-(void)dealloc
{
displayVC = nil;
if (adView) {
    [adView removeFromSuperview]; //Remove ad view from superview
    [adView setDelegate:nil];
    adView = nil;
}
[super dealloc];
}

-(void)adjustAdSize:(CGFloat)x :(CGFloat)y
{
   [UIView beginAnimations:@"AdResize" context:nil];
   [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.7];
   adView.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, 320, 50);
   [UIView commitAnimations];
}

-(BOOL)adWhirlTestMode
{
  return YES;
}

-(NSString *)adWhirlApplicationKey
{
  return @"xxxxxxxxxxxxx";
}

-(UIViewController *)viewControllerForPresentingModalView
{
  return displayVC;
}

-(void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner {
  [self adjustAdSize:0 :410];
}

@end
```

---

> myViewController.m

```
#import "adWhirlSingleton.h"

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

   adWhirlSingleton *adWhirlSingle = [adWhirlSingleton sharedAdSingleton];
   adWhirlSingle.displayVC = self;
   [adWhirlSingle adjustAdSize:0 :self.view.frame.size.height -50];
   [self.view addSubview:adWhirlSingle.adView];
   [self.view bringSubviewToFront:adWhirlSingle.adView];
   NSLog(@"Ad Banner View");
}
```

---

This is how i implemented the singleton class for `iAd` when i excute this i didnt get `iAd` displayed over my ViewController.
If anyone know how to implement this please help me to get out of this issue. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Just by including `ADBannerView.h` you won't get iAds anywhere. Not to mention that the correct import would be `#import <iAd/iAd.h>`. Check the documentation for sample code: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/iAdSuite/Introduction/Intro.html